# prefill Marketo fields on Submit

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, marketo

On submit of Marketo form it does some processing and returns back to the same page.

**My requirement**

I would like to have all the Marketo fields populated with the just entered data (data entered before clicking Submit button)for all the Marketo fields.

**What I have tried**

I have used the below code, that's given in http://developers.marketo.com/blog/external-page-prefill/

```
<script>
MktoForms2.whenReady( function(form) {
    //set the first result as local variable
    var mktoLeadFields = mktoLead.result[0];
    //map your results from REST call to the corresponding field name on the form
    var prefillFields = { 
            "Email" : mktoLeadFields.email,
            "FirstName" : mktoLeadFields.firstName,
            "LastName" : mktoLeadFields.lastName,
            "Company" : mktoLeadFields.company
            };
    //pass our prefillFields objects into the form.vals method to fill our fields
    form.vals(prefillFields);
    }
    );
</script>
```

But when the form submits and loads\returns back its not populated with previos entered data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the declared variable - here its

> var mktoLeadFields

(given in Q)  and made a logic that assigned the pre-enetered value to that var and then when set the form values with

```
form.vals(prefillFields);
```

it worked.